# Is Nietzsche's thought primarily a solution on how to classify people?

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, nietzsche, society, marxism

I was just now doing some super light reading on Nietzsche's aristocraticism. Seems to me that a lot of human history, both intellectual and social, is an attempt to create a stronger class system. Nietzsche's higher types being an example, sans god or gods.

I suppose even humanism could be seen as a dissonant form of this, classifying humans over anything else.

Is Nietzshe's thought part of a larger tendency, both in philosophy / art and society in general, toward a more robust classification of people? Of exclusion and hierarchy.

Has anyone claimed this?

Comment: It feels like this is articulating an "answer" to a much larger problem -- maybe something like: *what is the role of hierarchy and exclusion in political history (for Nietzsche)?* Possibly consider making some of this material an answer and refocusing the question appropriately?

Comment: @JosephWeissman i'm not sure i'm good enough at the internet to do so. sorry, i mean you're welcome to close and / or edit

Comment: So, possibly some of the adjustment might reconfigure the framing of the question. Note the question-form you use here is somewhat symptomatic -- being much closer to "am I right/what do you think" than to a neutral POV question about the role of a notion in the work of a thinker...

Comment: I guess the main task of philosophy is providing *destinctions*. And not only destinctions, but *justifications for destinctions*. In this sense, there should trivially be the tendency of creating ever more 'robust' systems of 'classes', i.e. categories. This, then, also applies to societies. The real question, as I take it, should be wether they are *pre*scriptive or rather *de*scriptive, i.e. wether history has the tendency to implicitely provide prescriptive classifications of people where there should be none.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking that's interesting, thanks. is there anything else which problematises categories?

Comment: In this context, the most obvious choice would be a variant Hume's is-ought problem.

Comment: @Philip Although I am sympathetic, I suspect that many postmodernists see their task not in providing distinctions but in dissolving them. Everything is just "text", "narrative", "discourse", there is nothing but "différance". They are in agreement on that even across the analytic/continental divide, anything goes, Derrida meets Feyerabend and Rorty.

Comment: I think this is also about Nietzsche's style and how he expressed his ideas as aphorisms . In addition to what @PhilipKlöcking pointed out Nietzsche  doesn't seem to follow a standard philosophical code . The dominant mode since rise of science in the west has been that philosophy is essentially an argument -- in particular a deduction . Examples of philosophers whose ideas are based on formal logical arguments include Descartes , Spinoza , John Stuart Mill and Kant . By this standard Nietzsche's work would be considered as art or rhetoric but not philosophy.

Comment: @Conifold: Yeah, that's pretty much what philosophy after the linguistic turn has become. But I disagree that this leads to dissolving distinctions, at least not necessarily. In my understanding, the main point here has been pointing out on which ontological/epistemological level the distinctions are made and how far they can be taken.

Comment: @shrey: According to many philosophers in early romanticist tendencies, this is philosophy proper. It is pretty much exactly what Hölderlin proposed, and many see Nietzsche as a somewhat twisted (and pretty late) romanticist.

Comment: unclear on why this is downvoted but plus ca change

Answer (score 1):

I cannot speak generally, but Neitzshe specifically postulates nature's ["will to power"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_to_power). He argues that all of nature, including humans, is motivated solely by moving up in various hierarchy's relative to others. All other actions and motives are derived from this will to power.

This philosophy *requires* the idea of classification and hierarchy, as without it there would be no higher state to will oneself to.

So, to answer your question: no, this is not part of some larger tendency, rather it is a fundamental principle of Nietzche's philosophy.

Comment: i'm sympathetic but you make authoritative *sounding* statements with no references, just a bit of wordplay, which itself only goes part way to saying what you do

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN I came to a logical conclusion based on the sources and ideas that I referenced you to. I don't see a problem

Comment: you *certainly* don't deduce that it isn't part of a larger tendency